# Can I make my wp-login.php to be run as index in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I want to know if I can make my wp-login.php to run as like index.php in WordPress? And if the user is already logged in it will go to index.php?

Comment: So you want to check if user has logged in on your site, and if user hasn't logged in, redirect to login page and vice versa?

Comment: basically on the top of index.php: `if(isset($_COOKIE['logincookie'])){return true;} else {header("Location: http://www.yoursite.com/wp-login"); }`

Comment: Or just like Dev mentioned, I was thinking about the wordpress logged in function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to the **bottom** of your wp-config.php:

```
if(!is_user_logged_in()){header("Location: http://yoursite.com/wp-login.php");} 
if(is_user_logged_in()){header("Location: http://yoursite.com");}
```

Comment: Meanwhile, you could read wordpress codex and find out if there's an user_not_logged_in() or similar.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) { header('location: wp-login.php'); } ?>
```

Comment: You can write in `index.php` or `wp-config.php`